# позиционирование Абсолют когда в боди 1 элемент

Tags: css, позиционирование

Элемент с позиционированием Абсолют позиционируются от 1 родителя с позиционированием не равным Статик.

В каком теге (элементе) будет позиционироваться единственный элемент в боди с позиционированием абсолют? (кто будет родителем для такого элемента?)

Comment: Родителем для абсолютного блока всегда относительный блок....если же нету блока с relative то родителем будет body

Comment: "если же нету блока с relative то родителем будет body"

Родителем body не будет, у него статик. Принудительно писал боди релетив и дочерний элемент перемещался.

Comment: вопрос закрыть так как не понятна суть вопроса